# ¿Cómo especificar la cantidad de decimales de un double?

Tags: c#, .net

Alguien me puede ayudar necesito que aparezcan 4 decimales
si tiene de tipo de dato `double`:

```
Console.WriteLine(num);
```

Por ejemplo se muestre 0.2544.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagino que tu problema es que la opción Math.Round redondea los valores y no quieres eso, si es el caso puedes conseguir "truncar" los decimales de la siguiente manera:

```
double value = 0.2544737373;
double num = (Math.Truncate(value * 10000) / 10000);
Console.WriteLine(num);
```

Como notarás, la cantidad de ceros en el valor auxiliar '10000' es la cantidad de decimales que quieres.

Puedes crear un extensionMethod para hacer esto más sencillo:

```
public static double Truncate(this double value, int decimales) 
{
      double aux_value = Math.Pow(10, decimales);
      return (Math.Truncate(value * aux_value ) / aux_value );
}
```

Y así llamar a Truncate directamente

```
double value = 0.2544737373;
double num = value.Truncate(4);
Console.WriteLine(num);
```

Answer (score 10):

La forma mas fácil:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:N4}", num);
```

En este caso la cadena de formato `N4` significa formato de número con 4 decimales.

Ten en cuenta lo siguiente:

- Si el número tiene mas decimales se truncarán en solo 4
- Si el número tiene menos se completa con ceros a la derecha
- Si el número no tiene decimales se completa igual con 4 ceros después del decimal

Más información sobre las cadenas de formato numérico: [Cadenas con formato numérico estándar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Si es solo para efectos de mostrarlo, puedes usar :

```
Console.WriteLine(num.ToString("N4"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede que con "Convert.ToInt32(value)" te sirva.

```
double x= 1.2;    
int c = Convert.ToInt32(x);
Console.WriteLine(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el metodo ToString para dejar un solo decimal a la derecha con el especificador de formato "F1".

```
double number = 34.4444444447;
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("F1"));
```

La salida será:

```
34.4
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Console.WriteLine(num.ToString("N2"));
```

`N` hace referencia a `Number`, lo que indicarías cuantos dígitos decimales quieres poner.