# ¿Cómo cambiar la forma en que se muestra un dato numérico en un textbox?

Tags: c#

Estoy realizando unos calculos de :
descuento, itbis, efectivo, devuelta etc.
me realiza los calculos perfectamente pero en algunos casos cuando la cantidad da decimal con muchos numeros . los muestra todos en el textbox es decir fijense en el textbox con el label devuelta:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay alguna forma de no mostrar tantos numeros o de redondear la cantidad?

```
        database.SoloNumeros(e);
        if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter))
        {
            double efectivo, devuelta, total;
            efectivo = Convert.ToDouble(txtefectivo.Text);
            total = Convert.ToDouble(txttotal.Text);
            devuelta = efectivo - total;
            txtdevuelta.Text = devuelta.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show("Por su Compra Señor/a" + txtnombre.Text, 
            "Gracias", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            txtefectivo.Enabled = false;
         }
```

Comment: ¿A cuántos decimales?, podrías revisar la pregunta [¿Cómo especificar la cantidad de decimales de un double?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/91442/c%C3%B3mo-especificar-la-cantidad-de-decimales-de-un-double/91464#91464)

Comment: a unos 2 o 3 o hasta 4 si es posible

Comment: ¿No hay un evento en la celda para cuando se modifica el valor (como `_Change`), para evitarte tener que hacer esa comparación con `Enter`? ¿Qué sucede si luego de escribir algo el usuario hace click en otro lugar y la celda pierde el foco?

Comment: si, me daba error asi ya lo arregle gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La clase String.format permite formatear una cadena.

Para tu caso especifico, puedes formatear la cadena usando algo así:

```
String.Format("{0:G2}",VariableConValor)
```

con eso, obtendrías un numero de la forma 65.27

Si quieres mas decimales, solo aclaralos en el formato, reemplazando el 2 por la cantidad de decimales que quieras.

Mas información de formatos:

[formatos numericos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Editado:

En el caso de tu codigo, deberia ser asi:

```
txtdevuelta.Text = String.Format("{0:G2}", devuelta);
```

Comment: ok, pero donde se supone que pongo ese codigo ? en que parte?

Comment: donde llenas el label... no se como lo llenas...

Comment: voy a editar la pregunta para mostrarte el codigo que lo llena

Comment: ya la edite revisa

Comment: @SamuelIgnacioSusanaConfesor fijate ahora si te sirve

Comment: me funciona pero con error en el txtdevuelta me muestra G2

Comment: @SamuelIgnacioSusanaConfesor ahi la edite. prueba ahora, disculpas me olvide de un detalle

Comment: perfecto gracias